# Error: Encrypted private direction is not setup properly

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, data-recovery, ecryptfs

Update 2:
I've used my MOUNT passphrase to use ecryptfs (which I got after adding universe as a repository) successfully, according to the terminal:

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /mnt/int-hdd
INFO: Found [/mnt/int-hdd].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: Y
INFO: Could not find your wrapped passphrase file.
INFO: To recover this directory, you MUST have your original MOUNT passphrase.
INFO: When you first setup your encrypted private directory, you were told to record
INFO: your MOUNT passphrase.
INFO: It should be 32 characters long, consisting of [0-9] and [a-f].

Enter your MOUNT passphrase: 
INFO: Success!  Private data mounted at [/tmp/ecryptfs.VbnX38Kv].
```

However, when navigating to the directory... all my files aren't there. Just the old friends "access-your-private-data" and "README.txt".
When I try to mount the directory, I get:

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp# cd ecryptfs.Vbn*
root@ubuntu:/tmp/ecryptfs.VbnX38Kv# dir
bin    dev   initrd.img      lib32   media  proc  sbin  sys  var
boot   etc   initrd.img.old  lib64   mnt    root  snap  tmp  vmlinuz
cdrom  home  lib         lost+found  opt    run   srv   usr  vmlinuz.old
root@ubuntu:/tmp/ecryptfs.VbnX38Kv# ecryptfs-mount-private
ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not setup properly
```

What now? How do I properly set up an encrypted private directory?
Am I missing some key step?

Update 1:
I'm trying to follow instructions to decrypt my home folder, but ecryptfs-recover-private only returns "command not found".
When trying to apt-get eryptfs-utils I only get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ecryptfs-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ecryptfs-utils' has no installation candidate
```

So what do I do to decrypt my files?

Original:
Messed up my Ubuntu install. The laptop is usable with a USBoot drive, but even after entering my encrypted drive's password - it's not usable.

I just have a bunch of apparently 'broken link' files dotted about.

What do I do?